# Social network platform with rest api

Tags: rest, social-networking

What are the various social network platforms available that can be used to generate REST api for basic social network functionalities like authentication, newsfeed, friends, groups over which we can build our own web/mobile clients ? self hosted solutions are preferred.

There is buddycloud. I am looking for other options.

Answer (score 0):

Buddycloud is such a service. http://buddycloud.com/ 
You can host it on your server too.